Not Authorized en webpay enviado por postman
Estuve probando Webpay, pero al encontrar problemas decidí intentar realizar la solicitud con Postman. Sin embargo, me sale el mensaje de error "Not Authorized", y creo que puede haber un error en el uso de curl. Aquí está el comando que utilicé:
curl --location --request POST 'https://webpay3gint.transbank.cl/rswebpaytransaction/api/webpay/v1.2/transactions' \
--header 'Tbk-Api-Key-Id: 597055555532' \
--header 'Tbk-Api-Key-Secret: 579B532A7440BB0C9079DED94D31EA1615BACEB56610332264630D42D0A36B1C' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "buy_order": "ordenCompra12345678",
    "session_id": "sesion1234557545",
    "amount": 10000,
    "return_url": "http://www.comercio.cl/webpay/retorno"
}'


{
    "error_message": "Not Authorized"
}


Espero que esas api key y secret sean falsos... De lo contrario, te recomiendo encarecidamente anularlos y generar unos nuevos.
